# Javascript - How to limit number of digits in Input Text Field

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, decimal, limit

Everyone! I want to limit numbers of digits in Input Text field using Javascript!
Supposed the input text field could allow only 2 or 3 digits and follow by 2 or 3 decimal digits too! **ex: 12.56; 12.567; 412.34; 412.344;..**

So could you please help with that! Really appreciate for your effort! Thanks

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Hi! I did researched and followed some instructions of Stack Overflow but it didn't work as the way it's supposed to be to! That's why I was asking something like that! People not always you wanted to be! Be realistic some time!

Comment: Well, it would be easier for us to help you, if you said what have you tried, and why it did not work. Otherwise, we take the risk of spending time repeating something you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex constraint in your text field as:

```
<input pattern = "[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{2,3}">
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your kind suggestion! But it didn't work like it's supposed to be! Anyway big thanks 

Comment: I believe you got the idea of regular expressions for string patterns. Read about it and you'll be able to write one as per your requirement.